# How do i address a successful transaction that should be rolled back when a subsequent write to the Firebase realtime database fails?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, transactions, batch-processing

In a Firebase cloud function, i have the following batch write which i assume is not enough to avoid race conditions, and that i should be using a transaction instead:

```
const updates = {};
updates[`rooms/${request.data.roomId}/memberTotal`] = admin.database.ServerValue.increment(1); // Increment member total
updates[`members/${request.data.roomId}_${request.auth.uid}`] = {
  dateJoined: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
  userId: request.auth.uid,
};
// Perform the batch update
try {
  await admin.database().ref().update(updates);
  // success
  return {
    success: true,
  }
} catch (error) {
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", "member set error", {details: error});
}
```

It is my understanding however, that in a transaction for the realtime database, i can only update one location in the database.

With that in mind, in the following revised code, i only insert the new `member` at another location subsequent to the transaction completing successfully, but this introduces an issue if the subsequent write fails, noted below:

```
try {
  const transactionResult = await admin.database().ref(`rooms/${request.data.roomId}`).transaction((currentRoomData) => {
    if (currentRoomData && currentRoomData.memberTotal !== undefined) {
      // Increment member total
      currentRoomData.memberTotal = (currentRoomData.memberTotal || 0) + 1;
      return currentRoomData;
    } else {
      // If the room doesn't exist or memberTotal is undefined, abort the transaction
      return undefined;
    }
  });

  if (transactionResult.committed) {
    // Perform the update for the member after the transaction
    const memberUpdate = {};
    memberUpdate[`members/${request.data.roomId}_${request.auth.uid}`] = {
      dateJoined: admin.database.ServerValue.TIMESTAMP,
      userId: request.auth.uid,
    };
    try {
      await admin.database().ref().update(memberUpdate);
      return { success: true };
    } catch (error) {

       // DO I ROLLBACK THE INCREMENTED FIELD HERE USING ANOTER TRANSACTION??
      
       throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", "member set error", { details: error });
    }
    
  } else {
    throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", "member set transaction aborted");
  }
} catch (error) {
  throw new functions.https.HttpsError("internal", "member set transaction error", { details: error });
}
```

What should i do if the subsequent write to `members/${request.data.roomId}_${request.auth.uid}` fails?

In that error case, the previous transaction would need to be rolled back given that this total represents the total number of members written to the `/members` location, but that does not seem like a practical approach.

Would removing the transaction from my main function and using the `onValueWritten` trigger to increment the total be a solution sufficient enough to avoid race conditions as follows instead?

```
onValueWritten("/members/{memberId}", (event) => {
        const roomId = context.params.roomId;

        // Reference to the counter
        const counterRef = admin.database().ref(`rooms/${roomId}/memberTotal`);

        // Run a transaction to increment the counter
        return counterRef.transaction(currentValue => {
            return (currentValue || 0) + 1;
        }).catch(error => {
            console.error('Incrementing memberTotal failed:', error);
        });
    });
```

Comment: "which i assume is not enough to avoid race conditions" Why? What race condition do you envision guarding against with the transaction?

Comment: A batch may very well be enough? I was under the impression that, using my example, if, say, 100 users, for arguments sake, attempt to "enter a chat room" at nearly the same time, that a batch update would not prevent a race condition. Is this not the case? What do you suggest i use? Just the batch operation, or the `onValueWritten` trigger instead of the batch?

Comment: A transaction is also not guaranteed to prevent that. You'll want to look at Firebase's security rules to ensure only valid permutations are allowed.

Comment: The order that members are added is not a concern. Really, i am just looking for a reliable way to keep an accurate count of the total number of records that exist at any given location in the realtime database. I used a very simple example to drive the point home, but in reality adding a member will result in updates to more than one location in my database, in addition to needing to keep an accurate total count of members that exist.

Comment: And as said, you'll need to write security rules to ensure only valid state transition can occur. Without that, transactions are just a friendly mechanism for clients to agree on such transition. Only a server-side mechanism like security rules can ensure the transitions meet your requirement.

Comment: I truly appreciate your response, it has motivated me to try, and i have submitted a possible solution as a result. Would you mind having a look?

Answer (score 1):

As per the comments above, according to [Frank van Puffelen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/209103/frank-van-puffelen), it should be possible to use a security rule in conjunction with my cloud functions to mitigate race conditions, and i believe i may have a valid implementation.

Would anyone be able to confirm if the following implementation will work as a solution?

1. In a cloud function designed to insert a new member, before doing so, id query the database for the existing member total located at `rooms/$roomId/memberTotal`.
2. Id add the existing `memberTotal` as an additional key value pair to the new member data and use a transaction to insert the new member to `members/$roomId_$uid`
3. I'd implement a separate `onValueWritten` trigger function which would only execute once a new member has been written to the database successfully. This trigger would use a transaction to increment the member total at `rooms/$roomId/memberTotal`.
4. Lastly, *and this is key,* id implement the following security rule to prevent a new member from being inserted if the existing `memberTotal` has changed:

   ```
    {
      "rules": {
        "members": {
          "$memberId": {
            // Ensure the provided memberTotal matches the actual memberTotal in the database
            ".validate": "newData.child('memberTotal').val() === root.child('rooms').child(newData.child('roomId').val()).child('memberTotal').val()"
          }
        },
      }
    }
   ```